# Find $\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{m}{(1-x)^m}-\frac{n}{(1-x)^n}\right)$ without using derivatives, the L'Hopital's rule or Taylor's series

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve this limit without using derivatives, the L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series:
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{m}{(1-x)^m}-\frac{n}{(1-x)^n}\right),
\quad m,n\in\mathbb N.
$$
I know that
$$
\frac{m}{(1-x)^m}= \frac{m}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{m-1})},
$$
$$
\frac{n}{(1-x)^n}= \frac{n}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1})},
$$
$$
\frac{m}{(1-x)^m}-\frac{n}{(1-x)^n}=
\frac{m(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1})-n(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{m-1})}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{m-1})(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1})},
$$
but I don’t know what to do next.

Comment: $a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-1})$

Comment: @zkutch How to apply this to further problem solving?

Comment: hmm... . If I write $a^n-b^n \ne (a-b)^n$ that it’s clearer this way?

Comment: If $m<n$ the ratio $(1-x)^n/(1-x)^m$ tends to $0.$ This means that $(1-x)^{-n}$ dominates $(1-x)^{-m}.$ Hence the limit of the difference does not exist if $n$ is odd and is equal $\infty$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: @Anne Bauval. Can you see the second and third formulas of the question?

Comment: "fruitless track" @Anne Bauval? Or essential mistake, which I emphasized in my second comment?

Comment: Assume for instance $m>n.$ $$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{m}{(1-x)^m}-\frac{n}{(1-x)^n}\right)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{mh^n-nh^m}{h^{m+n}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{mh^n}{h^{m+n}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac m{h^m}.$$

Comment: Thank You for understanding. It’s very strange that no one has seen this error for so many hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ denote the expression.

$(1)$ If $m=n$ then clearly the asked limit is zero.

$(2)$ $m$ and $n$ even with $m\gt n$

$E=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^n}\left(\dfrac{m}{(1-x)^{m-n}}-n\right)\to\infty(\infty-n)=\infty\times\infty=\infty$

$(3)$ $m$ and $n$ even with $m\lt n$.

Similarly to $(2)$ but we have now $E$ tends to $-\infty$.

Analogously if $m$ is even and $n$ is odd one has limit $\infty$ when $m\gt n$ and $-\infty$ when $m\lt n$ and if $m$ is odd and $n$ even the limit is $-\infty$ when $m\lt n$ and $\infty$ when  $m\gt n$.

(The proof in detail is leave for the O.P. and you can follow $(2)$ for it)